# Wordpress - Custom Gutenberg Block: Edit.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to create my own block to show recent products.

I was trying to create similar code for Products but I've a problem with this part:

```js
 const { posts } = useSelect(
  (select) => {
    const posts = select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'product', {
      per_page: numberOfItems,
      _embed: true,
    });
    return {
      posts: posts,
    };
  },
  [numberOfItems],
);
```

And the question is: How to get more info about products (e.g. price)?

Comment: Is "products" your own custom post type with a `price` as a meta value or are you using a plugin like WooCommerce or other?

Comment: It is the wocommerce post type.